# Populate end date of a month in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a two datefield textbox. In one field, i populate it by `getDate()` which returns the current date . But in another table i want to populate the exact the last date of that month.

For example:

Current date : `9/20/2012` in one text. Now, next date must be `9/30/2012`

Similarly,Current date : `01/14/2012` in one text. Now next date must be `01/31/2012`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class:

```
$date = new DateTime('9/20/2012'); 
echo $date->format('m/t/Y'); // t returns no. of days in a month
```

Output:

```
09/30/2012
```

[**Demo!**](http://codepad.org/14yJnwq7)

Comment: Who hates DateTime? I don't understand why was this downvoted...?

Comment: +1 to both answers that use DateTime. This solution would work only if you just needed to output the end of the month date as opposed to doing further calculations based on that date.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `date->modify()`:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('9/20/2012');
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('m/d/Y'); // 09/30/2012
?>

<?php
$date = new DateTime('10/20/2012');
$date->modify('last day of this month');
echo $date->format('m/d/Y'); // 10/31/2012
?>
```

Comment: +1 to both answers that use DateTime. This would be the better of the two if you needed to actually work with the end of the month date (like finding date intervals or such).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function daysInMonth(month,year) {
  var dd = new Date(year, month, 0);
  return dd.getDate();
}
```